# EFCore: How to detect which of the newly added entity's properties have changed since the dbContext Attach or Add happened?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, change-tracking

(trying to make my query clearer and not to confuse you):

In a WinForm app that makes use of EFCore, C# and SQLite,

What I am trying to achieve is this: I have a WinForm called AddNewVisitForm. I use it to Add a New Visit each time. Visit is a model of several properties. The form itself, contains many textboxes, one for each Visit's property.

When the form Loads, a new Visit entity is created

```
var newVisit = new Visit(); 
_dbContext.Add<Visit>(newVisit);
```

having the default value for each of its properties) and these new Visit's properties values are passed to all these textboxes initializing their contents.

Then the user starts entering new values to these textboxes altering their contents.

Then, at some point let's say, the user changes his mind and wants to cancel the AddNewVisit form and presses the Cancel button.

What I would like to do is, the form should be able to check (via dbContext detect changes probably) to see if any modifications to the newVisit entity have been made, warning the user that "Some modifications are made!!!. Really, you want to cancel?".

So, the user has to be informed of thesse changes made either by mistake or intentianally and then make his final decision!

Hope this makes clear why I need to know details of the entity changes apart from entity.Added state. Is there a way to be informed of changes made to the entity's properties before I call SaveChanges or simply discard all of them and close the form?

Thanx indeed for your time!!I would appreciate for your help

What I have tried so far is

```
 if (dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
 {
        dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
      Debug.WriteLine(_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
}
```

or

```
 EntityEntry<TFlatVisit> entry = _dbContext.Entry(newVisit);
    entry.DetectChanges();
    var modified = entry.Members.Where(m => m.IsModified).ToList();
    var modified2 = entry.Properties.Where(m => m.CurrentValue != m.OriginalValue).ToList();
    var modified3 = entry.Properties.Where(m => m.CurrentValue == m.OriginalValue).ToList();
```

None of them seems to work as expeted!!

PS: the exchange of data between the controls and the entity is being done via VisitBindingSource (eg. in the Load event I put  VisitBindingSource.DataSource = newVisit; and after the user presses the Cancel button I put VisitBindingSource.EndEdit();

Is there a way to accomplish this task?
I would appreciate if you could help me with this. Thanx a lot

Comment: I'm confused. How Add entity is related to Attach? If you create new entity it will always go to database.

Comment: By creating a new entity you only create an entity and that's all!! You can send it to the database either by adding it to the DbSet or by Attaching it and then call SaveChanges. But this is NOT what I am asking for!! My question is how can someone detect which entity's properties value have been changed/modified from the time it is Added or Attached to the dbContext until the SaveChanges is requested!! Hope that it is clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EntityEntry.Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.members?view=efcore-6.0):

> Provides access to change tracking information and operations for all properties and navigation properties of this entity.

```cs
var modified = ctx.Entry(message).Members
   .Where(m => m.IsModified)
   .ToList();
```

**UPD**

> None of them seems to work as expeted!!

No, they work pretty much as expected according to the goals of the change tracking and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries#using-dbcontextentry-and-entityentry-instances):

> For each tracked entity, Entity Framework Core (EF Core) keeps track of:
>
> - ...
> - The "original values" of properties, when this information is available. Original values are the property values that existed when entity was queried from the database.
> - ...

Since the entity is a newly created one there are no "original" values to track.

And I would argue that EF Core change tracker is not a right tool for you in this case - you should handle the stuff on the form itself and/or in the cancel key handler by analyzing the passed values and compare them to some "original"/"default" ones.

Comment: please have a look at it...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        var v = new Visit();
       dbContext.Add(v);
    
           v.LastName = "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
  
        EntityEntry<Visit> entry = _dbContext.Entry(v);
       entry.DetectChanges();
        var modified = entry.Members.Where(m => m.IsModified).ToList();
    }

Is that what you suggested?
modified returns 0;

Comment: @NAngelGr since the entity is in state added it does not make sense to track it's separate fields

Comment: please have a look at the initial question as I have tried to make clearer what I would like to achieve. Thanx for your time

Comment: thanx for your prompt response
The truth is that I would expect EFCore to be able to start tracking a newly added or attached entity using as original values the entity properties default values which to me at least makes sense!! But as far as I can see it's not capable of doing that. Right? Anyway Thanx again for your response. Now I don't know if I should tick your answer as the right one or the accepted one as I am new here

Comment: @NAngelGr again - I would argue that or newly created entries it does not make sense to spend additional effort on tracking properties cause you will need to save them all into the database no matter if they were changed one or multiple times, so why waist the effort. As for accepting the answer - feel free to accept and/or upvote it if it helped/answered your question.